# Java replace text with emoji

Tags: java, emoji

I made this class that will replace text to emoji. The code works fine at the moment but the look of the emoji isn't quite right.

They are like this:
[image]

But I rather have them like this:
[image]

I tried multiple different code formats, but nothing seems to work. Maybe I am searching on the wrong thing?

My class:

```java
package user;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EmojiReplacer {

    private final Map<String, Integer> emojis = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put(":)", 0x1F60A);
        put(":d", 0x1F604);
        put(";)", 0x1F609);
        put(":o", 0x1F62E);
        put(":p", 0x1F60B);
        put(":$", 0x1F633);
        put(":(", 0x1F615);
        put(":'(", 0x1F625);
        put(":|", 0x1F610);
        put(">:)", 0x1F608);
        put(">:(", 0x1F621);
        put(":]", 0x1F60F);
        put("<3", 0x2764);
    }};

    public String replaceString(String message) {
        String[] messagePieces = message.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < messagePieces.length; i++) {
            if (emojis.containsKey(messagePieces[i])) {
                messagePieces[i] = new String(Character.toChars(emojis.get(messagePieces[i])));
            }
        }
        return String.join(" ", messagePieces);
    }
}
```

Comment: The emojis look different depending on the platform or operating system. [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/) shows this partly for example with the [grinning face](https://emojipedia.org/grinning-face/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is whatever is rendering the emoji for you, not the string of text that you are rendering.  In other words, your code is working fine.

I just ran your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmojiReplacer test = new EmojiReplacer();
    System.out.println(test.replaceString(":) :d >:) :$"));
}
```

and I get this:

which looked good both in my IntelliJ output window, and here.  I'm on a Mac.

What is taking the String that your code produces, and producing the actual visual emojis for you?  Since the browser can obviously render them, have you tried copying the emojis that you think look wrong, and pasting them into your browser, like into your message.  The example of a bad emoji you show seems to be a screen shot, not the actual emoji rendered by the browser.

Comment: My result after copy pasting them: 
Both printing them to my output window and JavaFX give me the lined result and not with colors

Comment: How would I change this?

Comment: @Tygo, that would be a matter of whatever is displaying the characters.  It is that program that is choosing to interpret those special characters as certain symbols, and it decides the mapping and the particular symbols.  Everything I've tried on my Mac does the same thing, so it's possible that on Mac there is a shared set of symbols.  Maybe on Windows and/or Linux, it's different.  You can see from your black/white example in your question that whatever is rendering that emoji does know what it's doing...it's a smiley face, so it did get it right.  Guess it wants to stay away from color.